# Error appearing in jQuery .hover() implementation, but looks exactly like documentation example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement jQuery's hover function as I have done before and this is how I thought it is done and I'm looking at the jQuery API documentation and it looks like i'm doing it correctly, but I am getting an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } on line 4

Here is the code:

```
$('#dismissAllButton').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css({'color':'#000000', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css({'color':'#ffffff', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'});
    }
);
```

Comment: on what css attribute are you trying to apply the rgb(x, x, x) ? You are missing the key in the dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing keys in the objects inside `css()`, and that's a syntax error

```
$('#dismissAllButton').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css({'color':'#000000', borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css({'color':'#ffffff', borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'});
    }
);
```

I just used `borderColor` as an example

If the RGB colors are some sort of fallback, remove them, they are not needed